# htaccess Pass Protect Interfereing With Wordpress functionality

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My host asked me to implement [htaccess authentication](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/wordpress-login-brute-force-attack) to add an extra layer of security to my Wordpress installation.

When accessing the Wordpress admin area I am asked for a second (server) level of authentication. This is fine, however I have a page on my site that is pass protected. Unfortunately all users of this page are also being asked for the htaccess credentials.

Is there a better way to add this brute force protection? Or perhaps a way to exclude a specific page from requiring the second factor authentication?

Also, will the latter weaken and defeat the purpose of having the second login?

Here is the relevant code from the tutorial...

`ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
AuthName "Authorized Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/username/.wpadmin
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>`

Edit: Also this method doesn't seem viable for WP sites that have subscribers. Surely they would need to access wp-login.php.

Answer (score 3):

Should work if you use the following directives:

```
# passwordprotect wp-login.php
<Files wp-login.php>
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} != 'action=postpass'">
    AuthUserFile /path/to/passwd/file/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName 'Login Message'
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</If>
</Files>
```

What it does is, skipping the basic auth everytime the "action" string is provided and is "postpass".

... just a thought:

I need to test it further myself, because i don't know how it will affect the internal routing of Wordpress e.g. /action/postpass/.

Comment: It seems to work as intended for now. If it survives testing it seems to be one of the best solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why change the htaccess when you can change the WordPress password form. Here is something that worked for me.

```
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'wpsight_password_form_dmd' );
function wpsight_password_form_dmd($output){
    global $wp;
    $post   = get_post( $post );
    $label  = 'pwbox-' . ( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $output = '<form action="' . esc_url( home_url( $wp->request ).'/?postpassnew123=1' ) . '" class="post-password-form" method="post">
    <p>' . __( 'This content is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:' ) . '</p>
    <p><label for="' . $label . '">' . __( 'Password:' ) . ' <input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" /></label> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr_x( 'Enter', 'post password form' ) . '" /></p></form>
    ';
return $output;    
}
if(isset($_GET['postpassnew123'])){
    if ( !isset($_POST['post_password'] ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
        exit();
    }
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
    $hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );

    $expire  = apply_filters( 'post_password_expires', time() + 10 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );
    $referer = wp_get_referer();
    if ( $referer ) {
        $secure = ( 'https' === parse_url( $referer, PHP_URL_SCHEME ) );
    } else {
        $secure = false;
    }
    setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $hasher->HashPassword( wp_unslash( $_POST['post_password'] ) ), $expire, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );

    wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the page using a environment variable that matches against the requested URI:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access" 
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden" 

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/path/to/no-protect-page$ ok_uri=true

AuthName "Authorized Only" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/username/.wpadmin 
Require valid-user
Allow from env=ok_uri
Satisfy Any
```

So the directory where this htaccess file is placed will be password protected, *except* for requests to `/path/to/no-protect-page`.

Comment: OK great I'll try this. Will this meaningfully compromise the new security measures? Also the lines commencing <filesmatch> have been removed in your example, was that deliberate?

Comment: Also, will I need to move this to a new directory other than root?

Comment: @square_eyes the filesmatch was applying the authentication to **only** the `wp-admin.php` page. If that's what you want then add them back in, but that also means that your other URL wouldn't have been affected anyways

Comment: I'm guessing somehow my page calls wp-login.php which is why my page... let's call it /pagewithapass, was also requiring the htaccess auth.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/ ; https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulletproof-security/ or other security plugins on Wordpress.

Comment: I already have Wordfence running, I'd rather not install another security plugin if possible. Couldn't I just add a line to exclude my page from the auth request?

Comment: I thnk I found the include... `<?php if ( post_password_required() ) {
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="/wp-login.php?action=postpass">` And it does indeed appear to reference wp-login.php. But that still doesn't change the fact that when using yours above I'm not prompted to authenticate anywhere.